# php how to attach a if statement to a button?

Tags: php, button, isset

I have a I statement;

```
if($game_set->issue_challenge()){echo "test";}else {"test failed";}
```

and I have a button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I want to be able to say: `if the button isset, then $values = $_POST['gamelist'] and if($game_set->issue_challenge()){echo "test";}else {"test failed";}`

I was thinking something like

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$values = $_POST['gamelist']
if($game_set->issue_challenge()){echo "test";}else {"test failed";}
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: you have to do that in a client script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a POST form:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')) {
       ... it was clicked
    }
}
```